# React context api is empty on dynamically created component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have something like this
<AppContext.Provider value={}>...</AppContext.Provider>

Inside one of the children components I try to dynamically create component

```
...
 ReactDOM.render<T>(
        React.createElement(Component, {
          ...props,
          proceed: (val) => {
            ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(wrapper);
            resolve(val);
          },
        } as T),
        wrapper,
      );
```

Inside dynamically created component I try to use context

```
const ctx = useContext(AppContext)
```

Its empty object, with anything defined

Of course my context stores some data, and its defined/visible on statically created components

Is there any solution (except passing as props) to read context from dynamically created components? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not only creating a dynamic component, you are also calling the deprecated `render` on `ReactDOM`, which creates a new *independent* React tree. There is no connection between that tree and the already existing tree. This is the mistake that needs to be fixed.

It looks like you are building some sort of dialog/popup. You want to use [React Portals](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) for this. With a react portal, you can render a component in a different place in the DOM, while still being inside the existing React tree

For this, you would need to have some sort of parent container that houses your wrapper code, then renders each opened one using the following as an example:

```
let KEYCOUNTER = 1;
function PopupProvider({children}) {
const [pupups, setPopups] = useState([]);

function openPopup(children) {
    const key = KEYCOUNTER++;
    // consider using the same wrapper element for each popup, this makes the code WAY easier
    const wrapper = createElement...
    setPopups(old => [...old, {
        key: 
    }])
}
function closPopup(key) {
    // find in popups, then delete the wrapper 
}

return (
// The following would be way better with memoization
<PopupContext.Provider value={{ openPopup, closePopup }}>
  {children}
  {openedPopups.map(popup => createPortal(popup.children, popup.wrapper, popup.key)}
</>
);
```

Comment: I know that ReactDOMs render is deprecated, and its old react version. We have a new next's version fixed but in another branch, still not in production, thank you for answering, will check this and return with the answer

Comment: I have read docs, and yeah you understood me right, but in my case, unfortunately this does not work. Don't know why
There is click event, after that dynamic component call with Promise inside it (promise resolves when mouseup event triggered)